# unable to delete account using param tag

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my code

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="getmyacceditdel">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myaccount}" var="acc" columnsWidth="90px" >

        <apex:column headerValue="EDIT">
         <apex:outputLink value="{!acc.id}e" id="edit">EDIT</apex:outputLink>
           </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="DELETE">
             <apex:commandLink action="{!delacc}">Del
              <apex:param name="idtodel" value="{!acc.id}" assignTo="{!recid}"/>
               </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                     <apex:commandLink value="{!acc.name}" action="{!accountclicked}" reRender="contable">
                      <apex:param name="idtocon" value="{!acc.id}" assignTo="{!recid}"/>
                      </apex:commandLink>
                       </apex:column>

             </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>                         
                                          <apex:pageblock >
                                         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactinfo}" var="c" id="contable">
                                        <apex:column value="{!c.firstname}"/>
                                       <apex:column value="{!c.lastname}"/> 
                                     </apex:pageBlockTable>                                         
                                   </apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public with sharing class getmyacceditdel {

   public list<contact>contactinfo{get;set;}
   public string recid{set;get;}


    public pagereference delacc() {
      Account ac=[select id,name from account where id=:recid];
       delete ac;

       pagereference ref = new pagereference('apex/getmyacceditdel');
       ref.setredirect(true);
       return ref;
         }


    public list<Account> getMyaccount() {
        return[SELECT id,name from Account ORDER BY lastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT:10];
    }

    public void accountclicked() {
    contactinfo =[select id,firstname,lastname from contact where AccountId=:recid];
     }


}
```

When am trying to delete the account,the error message displayed is

> Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.

Can any one please correct the code.

Comment: When exactly is the error occuring - on saving the page or on clicking the "Del" link?

Comment: @Rob hi.... when am clicking the del link then am getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, try changing:

```
pagereference ref = new pagereference('apex/getmyacceditdel');
```

To:

```
pagereference ref = new pagereference('/apex/getmyacceditdel');
```

Note the forward slash `/` at the start of the PageReference constructor argument.

See the [official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_ctor_2.htm) on the `PageReference(partialURL)` constructor for more details.

Comment: I had this error few days ago and this should definitely work.

Comment: @Rob...hey thank you it worked.....i  was able to delete the custom accounts i have created .I think we can edit the standard accounts but we can't delete them...is that right..?